# Stack multiple plots vertically in R or Python

Tags: python, r, plot

I am trying to reproduce the plot below, which shows the mean and standard deviation in separate sections of the y-axis. Rather than plotting them in separate subfigures, they share the x-axis.

[image: this plot]

I see [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11794436/stacking-multiple-plots-vertically-with-the-same-x-axis-but-different-y-axes-in) to use the `lattice` library in R, but I'd like to do it with labels to the side, instead of separating each graph—as in the example I've provided.

Comment: If using Python + Matplotlib, use subplots like in fourth figure here:  http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `R`, here's a `ggplot2` version:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

# Fake data
set.seed(2)
n = 20
dat = data.frame(mp=rep(seq(0,1,length=n),2),
                 group=rep(LETTERS[1:2], each=n),
                 Mean=rep(c(1,1.1),each=n)*seq(0.7,0,length=n),
                 SD=rep(c(0.1,.12), each=n) + rnorm(2*n,0,0.02))

dat = melt(dat, id.var=c("mp","group"))
dat$variable = factor(dat$variable, levels=c("SD","Mean"))

ggplot(dat, aes(mp, value, colour=group)) +
  facet_grid(variable ~ ., scales="free", space="free", switch="y", ) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=0.6, colour="grey40", linetype="11") +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=function(x) {round(seq(0,max(x),length=5)[-5],1)}) +
  expand_limits(y=c(0,0.2)) +
  labs(x="Mixing Parameter", y="") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.spacing.y=unit(0,"lines"),
        strip.placement="outside",
        strip.background=element_rect(fill=NA, colour=NA)) +
  guides(colour=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: It's important to me that I recreate the plot *as closely as possible*. Your answer has a space between the graphs and a sub-label to the side. kliimat's answer works for Python, and if you can make that work for R, I'm happy to mark it as the solution.

Comment: By "Sub-label" do you mean the legend on the right? Also, do you want the facet labels ("SD", and "Mean" on the right or do you want them to the left, outside the axis values